# How to sent message to all memeber in server?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Discord version: 12.2.0
How I sent embed to all members in private chat->(DM)?

```js
if (message.content === 'invite') {
  message.guilds.send(embed)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can message all the members in the guild the message was sent in by looping through the members and sending them the message

```js
const members = await message.guild.members.fetch()
members.forEach((member) => member.send(embed))
```